# Long request freeze mysql server

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

i'm working on a 5.7 Mysql server with MyISAM tables.

All my tables ares used by internal software for my customers. (and the tables, defined indexes, and storage type are imposed by the software)

I have create somes of request for generate reports. My reports work with multiples joined tables and lot of conditions. A request can make 5 minutes for display a result.

**My problem is not the time ( because it's really due to the complexity of request). But during the request, all connexions are freezed and the users can't works.**

> Have you some idea for change this situation ( i have already
>   optimised my requests, and y can't work more on this side) ?

i search a solution about concurrent access, or other solutions.

note : my request are "read only".

thanks for help, and sorry for my lack of english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Change engines

First thing to do, if at all possible, is probably change `MyISAM` by `InnoDB`, which handles concurrency much better. See "[MyISAM vs InnoDB](http://blog.danyll.com/myisam-vs-innodb/)", specially the point about "Table-locking vs Row-locking". I quote them:

> When a query runs against a `MyISAM` table, **the entire table in which it is querying will be locked**. This means subsequent queries will only be executed after the current one is finished. If you are reading a large table, and/or there are frequent read and write operations, this can mean a huge backlog of queries.
>
> When a query runs against an `InnoDB` table, only the row(s) which are involved are locked, the rest of the table remains available for CRUD operations. This means queries can run simultaneously on the same table, provided they do not use the same row.

[emphasis mine]

### Option 2: Master/Slave replication

Another possible (although probably not cheap) solution is to have your database being **[replicated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) using an asynchronous Master/Slave setup**. [I guess that if you cannot change from MyISAM to InnoDB, it won't be easy to setup a replicated DB... but I don't know either your possibilities nor your limitations.]

Your users (i.e.: your application) should always be working with your *Master* node, and all `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s should **always and only** be executed there. The `SELECT`s can be executed in either node, taking into account that the *Slave* might be slightly not up-to-date. The `SELECT`s that take a long time *should* be executed in the *Slave*, so all the users in the *Master* node are not blocked at all.

The *Slave* node can not be completely up-to-date (as the replication is asynchronous, it can lag behing the master by anything from a few miliseconds to a long time, if the *Slave* could not process the updates from the master and they "accumulate").

This kind of scenario is not uncommon in applications where you have the *Master* node working with a setup optimized for [OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) (OnLine Transaction Processing); and the *Slave* node with a setup optimized for [OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) (OnLine Analytical Processing). OLTP means (mostly) entering and manipulating data, and making relatively simple queries, with small amounts of data every time, whereas OLAP means querying data, normally in large amounts and with aggregations and computations (i.e.: analysis and reporting).